# How to keep PyQt GUI alive while doing heavy calculation and updating Progress bar and logger

Tags: qgis-3, qgis-plugins, pyqgis-3, pyqt5

I have a GUI designed with PyQt, this GUI has a progress bar and a logger.
when the user clicks the Run button the GUI/QGIS will become "No responding"
the actions normally take 45minutes to 1hr

to make it easyi just put the concept I use in my program

```
class maindlg:
    def __init__(self):
        pass
    
    def __run(self):
        #this will be called when every user clicks the Run button
        heavyCalculation(self).heavyFunction()
    
    def updateProgressbar(self):
        #updates progress bar with some logic
        pass
    
    def logAction(self,value):
        # there is a log textbox  and with some logic this will write the logs
        pass
        
class heavyCalculation:
    def __init__(self,maindlg):
        self.maindlg=maindlg
        
        pass
    
    def heavyCalculation(self):
        #in Here I modify all layers, all geomerty and for each action I update progress bar and logger
        self.maindlg.updateProgressbar()
        self.maindlg.logAction('action xyz done!')
```

How can I keep GUI(progress bar and the logger) alive while I do the heavy calculation?

I have already tried QgsTask, but it doesn't work form me as in [cookbook](https://docs.qgis.org/3.16/en/docs/pyqgis_developer_cookbook/tasks.html) clearly mentions "must NEVER use any QgsVectorLayer, QgsProject or perform any GUI based operations"

I tried using threads but my knowledge isn't enough and QGIS Crashes when I am trying to update the logger and progress bar from the second Thread.

how this can be achieved in QGIS 3x

Ps. the heavy calculation code works well the only problem is the qgis and GUI are not responding while the code is being executed.

Comment: After sending updates to the logger and the progress bar, you can call `QCoreApplication.processEvents()` (see [the docs](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qcoreapplication.html#processEvents)). Warning: use it wisely and only when required. Here you have a [simple example](https://github.com/SwissTierrasColombia/Asistente-LADM-COL/blob/7ae212d1bf35b5dae74c6977f1d8e985e792155c/asistente_ladm_col/lib/logger.py#L120). Note that in this way you could also allow users to cancel ongoing heavy calculations, as you may *listen* to cancel button clicks and react accordingly.